# Cannot align text in TableViewRow using

Tags: titanium-alloy

I have a TableViewRow setup as follows:

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow id="eventRow" dataId="" model="{eventId}">
        <View>
            <Label id="eventName" text="{eventName}"/>
        </View>
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

And the style like this:

```
"#eventRow":{
    height:44
}

"#eventName":{
    textAlign:"left"
}
```

However, when the items are shown in the tableView, the text alignment is center, not left. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the left property

```
"#eventName":{
    textAlign:"left"
    left : "0dp"
}
```

Comment: BTW I would recommed using listViews and not tableViews,  you will find that you are getting better performance.

Answer (score 0):

add  into tss file

```
"#eventName": { left: 0}
```